# how to automatically start clojure application on boot

Tags: clojure

I'm just looking to run a ring server on bootup. I'm using ubuntu 12.04 and was wondering how other people deployed their apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The upstart cookbook was pretty daunting... but it was easier than I thought. The upstart script is actually quite straight forward to write.

Here are the steps I took to get it working:

#### (1) In your project.clj, put a `:main` keyword pointing to the class to run. eg:

```
(defproject lapis "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :dependencies ...
  ... rest of file ...
  :main lapis.app)
```

#### (2) Then in the class, add a `:gen-class` directive to the namespace as well as a `-main` function:

```
(ns lapis.app
  (:gen-class)
  (:use ....)
  (:require...))

(defn -main [&args]
  ......)
```

#### (3) Use lein uberjar in to generate the jar file:

```
$ lein uberjar
> Including fs-1.3.2.jar
> Including jetty-io-7.6.1.v20120215.jar
> ........
> Including jetty-continuation-7.6.1.v20120215.jar

> Created /home/example/lapis/target/lapis-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar
```

#### (4) Make sure that the `.jar` file runs:

```
$ java -jar target/lapis-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar
```

and also test it outside of your project directory because there may be problems with files in your `resources` directory that you may not be aware of:

```
$ cd ~
$ java -jar /home/example/lapis/target/lapis-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar
```

#### (5) If everything works, the upstart file is placed in /etc/init/.conf.

My script was 5 lines:

```
$ cat /etc/init/lapis.conf
> -------------
> start on started

> script
>  exec /usr/bin/java -jar  /home/example/lapis/target/lapis-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar >> /var/log/lapis/lapis.log 2>&1
> end script
> --------------
```

#### (6) Test to see if the service works:

```
$ sudo start lapis
>  lapis start/running, process 2543

$ sudo stop lapis
> lapis stop/waiting
```

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to generate init or upstart scripts. The [leiningen wiki](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/wiki/Plugins) mentions [lein-init-script](https://github.com/strongh/lein-init-script) which automates generating and installing the scripts.